# Is this a videogame question only website?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

If there is a website with questions that aren't videogames can you tell me what they are?

Comment: There's a board and card games stackexchange if that's what you're looking for. That should cover most non-videogames

Answer (score 0):

Top right corner of your page, the speech bubble icon. Click to see "a list of all 174 stack exchange sites".